# MySQL - Can any other insert will happen between bulk insert

Tags: mysql

Consider a MySQL table with 1000 rows, where the maximum primary key (Id) is 1000. Now, if I insert 10000 rows into the table using a bulk insert with an insert query, will my 10000 inserts start from 1001 to 11000, or is there a chance that some other inserts may occur in between my 10000 rows?

Comment: Why not try it out and see what happens? Inserting 10'000 rows in a table that should hold no more than 1'000 rows sounds pretty strange to me

Comment: If you don't lock the whole table - there is a chance some other INSERT can sneak in between.

Comment: @user1191247 this is not true, see the answer to the duplicate question.

Comment: @Shadow Thanks. Deleted! I completely missed default auto Inc lock mode changing from consecutive to interleaved in MySQL 8. My bad!

Comment: As long as your inserts are "[simple inserts](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/innodb-auto-increment-handling.html#innodb-auto-increment-lock-mode-interleaved:~:text=mode%E2%80%9D%20inserts.-,%E2%80%9CSimple%20inserts%E2%80%9D,-Statements%20for%20which)", which this one is, _"there are no gaps in the numbers generated for a single statement"_, but you may have other concurrent statements which are not "simple" (See last para of [innodb_autoinc_lock_mode = 2](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/innodb-auto-increment-handling.html#innodb-auto-increment-lock-mode-interleaved)).